Dantzig-Wolfe Pricing Problem: Find Extreme Points
Consider Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition on MILP $\min \{ cx \mid Ax \geq b, Dx \geq d, \mathbb{Z}^k\times\mathbb{Q}^l \}$.
The extended formulation is yielded by applying Minkowski-Weyl theorem to reformulate $X := \{ x \in \mathbb{Z}^k\times\mathbb{Q}^l \mid Dx \geq d \}$ as a convex combination of extreme points of $\text{conv}(X)$.
To apply column generation, we need to find extreme points of $\text{conv}(X)$ with negative reduced cost. For this, the literature suggests to instead solve the pricing problem, which is essentially the MILP $P$: $\min \{ \text{redcost(x)} \mid Dx \geq d,  x \in \mathbb{Z}^k\times\mathbb{Q}^l \}$, whereas $\text{redcost(x)}$ denotes the linear expression to calculate reduced cost of a column $x$.
Why is this correct? Why can all extreme points of interest be found by solving an MILP?
I think it boils down to the following: set of feasible solutions of $P$: $\{ x \in \mathbb{Z}^k\times\mathbb{Q}^l \mid Dx \geq d \}$ contains all extreme points of $\text{conv}(X)$ (why?), every optimal solution of a MILP is an extreme points of the convex hull of it's feasible region, so optimal solutions of $P$ are extreme points of $\text{conv}(X)$

Just for clarification, 1) the Minkowski-Weyl theorem said, a convex combination of extreme points + non-negative linear combination of extreme rays. You should check both. 2) The pricing problem can be solved exactly or in a heuristic manner to find the column(s) with the most appropriate reduced cost. The column can be either the extreme points or the extreme rays or a combination of both.

3) To check why this is correct you should check the pivoting mechanism of the simplex algorithm and how a new column can be replaced in the basis. The magic is to solve the master problem with a few number of columns rather than the original problem. Please, keep in mind that we are talking about an LP, not MILP.

Your $\mathbb{Q}$ should instead be $\mathbb{R}$  throughout.

The original problem is $$\min \{ cx \mid Ax \ge b, Dx \ge d, \mathbb{Z}^k\times\mathbb{R}^l \}.$$  Let $X = \{ x \in \mathbb{Z}^k\times\mathbb{R}^l \mid Dx \geq d \}$. The original problem can then be rewritten as $$\min \{ cx \mid Ax \ge b, x\in X \}.$$
To solve this, Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition first solves a relaxation
$$\min \{ cx \mid Ax \ge b, x\in \text{conv}(X)\}.$$
This is an LP but is at least as strong as the usual LP relaxation because
$$X\subseteq \text{conv}(X) \subseteq  \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^k\times\mathbb{R}^l \mid Dx \geq d \}.$$
Now apply Minkowski-Weyl to the polyhedron $\text{conv}(X)$. The resulting subproblem is $$\min\{\text{redcost}(x) \mid x\in \text{conv}(X)\},$$ but we typically don’t explicitly know $\text{conv}(X)$, so instead solve the equivalent problem $$\min\{\text{redcost}(x) \mid x\in X\}.$$
